# How to limit the choice of the Fields.Selection in python

Tags: python, odoo

I have a fields types selection  with the following values:

```
_CATEGORY_SELECT = [  ('tap','Finished products'),
                      ('nvl','Materials'),
                      ('lik','Components'),
                      ('hth','Item consumption'),
                      ('dlk','workwear Supplies periodical'),
                      ('dlx','manufacturing workwear'),
                      ]
```

Now I want to do this when I chose Fields will only show 2 values and to select the `dlx, dlk`.
So how I do?
Hope to receive your help.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

```
[x for x in _CATEGORY_SELECT if x[0] in ['dlx','dlk']]
```

Comment: I ask that I would use this in any position in the code are not? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `filter()`

`filter(lambda x:  x[0] in ['dlx','dlk'], _CATEGORY_SELECT)`

Comment: I ask that I would use this filter() in any position in the code are not? Thanks